# SVG path hover fill with background. Teritory Plan very advanced

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Is there a simply way, to use a svg path hover with images? I need to make a flor plain, teritory plain, there is a 3 house plan. Path and hover works, but there is a problem to on hover put a image, that is a lighter that other areas, or it there a way to use opacity hover?

Here is a demo:

http://wpbaltic.com/svg/

```
<div class="house">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 3204.32 2001.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 3204.32 2001.2;"
         xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="Layer_1">
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;" d="M1524.416,920.84l222.542-113.869l71.469,16.848l10.772,287.96
            L1182.3,1504.114l-549.336-410.799v-184.86l71.236-31.495l-20.549-16.432l130.142-34.233l426.044,230.048l283.573-131.456
            l-16.139-4.487L1524.416,920.84z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Layer_2">
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;" d="M2039.992,984.159L1831.18,1110.8l-10.772-287.96l-71.469-16.848
            l-222.542,113.869l-17.146-0.44l-190.719-53.025l-9.589-146.518l35.618-19.171l4.11-28.756l113.703-45.188l149.321,41.08
            l63.016-24.648l363.028,87.637L2039.992,984.159z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Layer_3">
        <polygon style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;" points="2586.798,832.119 2491.695,885.328 2486.034,846.837 
            1863.338,648.72 1864.47,482.302 1933.533,457.396 1957.309,461.924 1992.406,456.264 2566.419,605.701 2569.815,637.399 
            2596.987,653.248    "/>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you try to reword your question. I'm not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Here is a example what i meen. http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Comment: So you want to use your path to clip the image?

Comment: Yes. I need a lighter path selection, use bg image or opaticy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set opacity CSS on hover like this.

```css
:hover {
  opacity : 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="house">
     <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
         viewBox="0 0 3204.32 2001.2"
         xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="Layer_1">
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:black;" d="M1524.416,920.84l222.542-113.869l71.469,16.848l10.772,287.96
            L1182.3,1504.114l-549.336-410.799v-184.86l71.236-31.495l-20.549-16.432l130.142-34.233l426.044,230.048l283.573-131.456
            l-16.139-4.487L1524.416,920.84z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Layer_2">
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:black;" d="M2039.992,984.159L1831.18,1110.8l-10.772-287.96l-71.469-16.848
            l-222.542,113.869l-17.146-0.44l-190.719-53.025l-9.589-146.518l35.618-19.171l4.11-28.756l113.703-45.188l149.321,41.08
            l63.016-24.648l363.028,87.637L2039.992,984.159z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Layer_3">
        <polygon style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:black;" points="2586.798,832.119 2491.695,885.328 2486.034,846.837 
            1863.338,648.72 1864.47,482.302 1933.533,457.396 1957.309,461.924 1992.406,456.264 2566.419,605.701 2569.815,637.399 
            2596.987,653.248    "/>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```